# Spoken Language Dataset of L2 Acquisition

Tags: computational-linguistics, language-acquisition, datasets, spoken-language

Is there a publicly available dataset of spoken language for L2 acquisition? I would prefer children learning an L2, but any age range is fine. It would be great, but not necessary, to have speaking samples for each speaker in their L1 as well as L2.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `learners corpus` into the search slit of the [Virtual language observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu) and you will find a plethora of resources.

Answer (score 0):

[CHILDES Transcripts and Media](http://childes.psy.cmu.edu/access/) is a database for records of children acquiring languages, including both transcripts and audio/video files.
I'm not sure though if there is something on second language acquisition, at least they have media for bilingual children. Maybe that helps too.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted please tell me what the reason was so I can improve my post?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you clearly do not answer the question asked by the original poster.

Comment: I don't see why this *clearly* doesn't answer his question; I said that I don't know exactly if it also contains something about SLA, haven't worked with the database myself, but there definitely is something on bilingualism which goes in the right direction, possibly also SLA and it could be worth taking a closer look at it, so I thought this is better than nothing.